# Trim all spaces in UVMap

Tags: texturing, uv

How can I make the UVMap make all the vertices appear without any spaces? What I want to achieve is to use a tile texture to repeat over the 3d model. Now I have spaces, so the result is a patchy representation of the texture due to the spaces between the vertices in the UVMap.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your UV map and what you mean?